# How to solve CodeIgniter PHP error Message: Undefined variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-blade

I made a view page in CodeIgniter using blade with name "preeti-to-unicode.blade.php"

View:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>PREETI</h4>
    <form method="GET">
        <input id ="input-preeti" class="form-control" name="preeti" value="{{ $input_preeti }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 1em 0;">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>UNICODE</h4>
<input class="form-control" name = "unicode" readonly value="{{ $output_unicode }}">
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function preeti()
{
    $preeti_rule =
[
    "a" => "d",
    "b" => "k",
    "v" => "l",
    "r" => "t",
    "i" => "g",
    "y"" => "s"
];
    $input_preeti = $this->input->get('preeti');
    $output_unicode = join('',
    array_map(function($convert_unicode) use($preeti_rule) {
                      return $preeti_rule[$convert_unicode] ?? null; },
                      str_split($input_preeti)));

    $this ->load->blade('index.preeti-to-unicode',[
        'preeti' => $input_preeti,
        'unicode' => $output_unicode,

    ]);
}
```

I am getting following error when I load preeti-to-unicode.blade.php page.Both error is in same page
[Error Message1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPW86.png)
[Error Message2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvJEX.png)

I tried too much to solve this issue but same error message displayed,I think error is in controller page in this part.

```
        $this ->load->blade('index.preeti-to-unicode',[
        'preeti' => $input_preeti,
        'unicode' => $output_unicode,
```

Comment: You've provided the name to use in the template file, If you want to access `$input_preeti` in the template, it's under `preeti`. E.g. `{{ $input_preeti }}` should be `{{ $preeti }}`

Comment: @JonStirling I am accessing value of $input_preeti as $input_preeti = $this->input->get('preeti')

Comment: Irrelevant. `'preeti' => $input_preeti,` sets the controller's `$input_preeti` to the templates `$preeti`. That's how it works.

Comment: @JonStirling Thank You it solved my problem,I used {{ $preeti }} instead of {{ $input_preeti }} and it solved my problem :)

Comment: @JonStirling I was unaware that value was stored under $preeti and $unicode .I finally got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending this array to the view

```
['preeti' => $input_preeti, 'unicode' => $output_unicode,]
```

It is the keys of the array - `preeti` and `unicode` - that become variable names in the view.

So, this call

```
value="{{ $input_preeti }}"
```

should be

```
value="{{ $preeti }}"
```

Use of `$output_unicode` should be `$unicode`

Or, you could change the view data array keys